# Why is my HP PC apparently possessed by demons? ("Ghost loudspeaker".)

Tags: audio, motherboard, hardware-failure

I have a "HP Z240 Tower Workstation" PC, bought new 2019. I have my headphones plugged directly into the "middle audio connector" in the back (I believe -- it's the only one which works). It allows me to hear the audio output in the headphones.

As always happens, my headphones started glitching (those expensive audio cables seem to be deliberately made to go bad with time), so I jerked around the connector in the back of the PC, trying to make it use both left and right channels again (which usually works). Since it didn't work this time, I pulled it out in order to re-insert it, hoping that would fix it, with the music still playing.

Now, I was shocked to hear the music continuing even when the cable was pulled out! But the music didn't come from the headphones, but... from inside the PC? At first, I thought I was dreaming, tripping or had gone daffy. It really freaked me out and still does.

It seems as if it has a speaker *inside of it*! Almost like those old, very simple "PC Speakers" which could (mostly) only produce blips and blops. But I've never seen a computer with a built-in loudspeaker inside of it like that. I certainly didn't see any such thing when I closely inspected the internals after I had received the machine.

I don't get it. What's the purpose of this? It's a major damn security risk, because what if I'm listening to something sensitive and don't expect it to continue when I pull out the headphone cable? Seems like there is just no attention whatsoever to security/privacy anymore. I don't even understand what the "point" of this is, since it's way too bad quality and low in volume (but still "noisy") to actually be used for listening to music by any reasonable person.

It's not even meant to be a "consumer" PC, but more of a workstation, so it makes even less sense for this one.

I even checked the manual and couldn't find any mention of "loudspeaker".

Can somebody explain this? Have demons taken over this machine?

Comment: I'm familiar with this model of PC. It does have an internal speaker. You can disable it in the bios.

Comment: Lots of computers have internal basic speakers, and they play more than "bleeps and bloops"

Answer (score 3):

Many pre-built computers have built in speakers that play more than "bleeps and bloops", and the standard behavior of systems is to play the audio through whichever device is currently set as the output device.

You're not describing demons or security issues, you're just riled up over something entirely normal that you didn't expect.

Answer (score 0):

> I even checked the manual and couldn't find any mention of "loudspeaker".

This is why you should keep search terms generic when trying to find all instances of something.

Instead of searching for "*loud*speaker", you should have just searched for "speaker".

[image]

Although not wrong, "loudspeaker" is quite archaic now and not a good search term for this sort of situation, where it will cause references to the more commonly used "speaker" to be excluded from your search results.